# Automatic load jquery when page loaded in laravel using bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have page to show data using jquery and bootstrap table in laravel :
 In body I have hidden type to parse value to jquery :
 `<input type="hidden" name="compName" id="compName" value="">`

The jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#attendanceTable').bootstrapTable({
    classes: 'table table-striped',
    striped: true,
    formatLoadingMessage: function(){ return '<img src="public/assets/images/cui-loading.gif" width="30px"/>';},
    url: '{{ URL::route("get_data_attendance") }}',
    queryParams:function(p){
        p.iSearch = $('#iSearch').val();
        p.compName = $('#compName').val();
        return p;
    },
    pagination:true,
    sidePagination:'server',
    columns: [{
        field:'nik',
        title:'NIK',
    },{
        field:'date',
        title:'DATE',
    },{
        field:'staffname',
        title:'NAME',
    },{
        field:'in',
        title:'IN',
    },{
        field:'out',
        title:'OUT',
    }]
});

$('.filterTable').on('click',function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#attendanceTable').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
    url: 'http://portal.rodalink.com/attendance/data',
    queryParams:function(p){
        p.iSearch = $('#iSearch').val();
        p.compName = $('#compName').val();
        return p;
    }
    }); 
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   $('.filterTable').trigger('click');
});
```

});

The problem is : jquery cant get the compName parameter when page is loaded, but if I click search button or refresh the page jquery can get the compName parameter. How to handle this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `#compName` tag loaded by AJAX (later in page) or is it loaded directly on load ?

Comment: loaded directly on load (when page is loaded)

Comment: Can you try to put a break point in the loading function `queryParams` and ensure via the console that jQuery doesn't find the tag ?

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you means because Im new in Jquery. But here the response when first time page loaded :
http://portal.rodalink.com/attendance/data?limit=10&offset=0&order=asc&iSearch=&compName= 
When I refresh or click search button : http://portal.rodalink.com/attendance/data?limit=10&offset=0&order=asc&iSearch=&compName=IS1-L0302390

Comment: I don't have access to that (need username/password). If you use Chrome (but other browsers all have these), you can click on the "Options" button (the three horizontal lines button) and the on "More tools->Dev tools". There, there is a tab called "Source" from which you can put break points in your JavaScript and also a tab "Console" from where you type live JS code.

Comment: I will try, thank for your information